# Can I add a value to a int when a button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, button, pressed

Hi I'm new to programming

My concept is that I want to add 1 to an int type every time I press the button

Is it possible? If yes what's the simplist code to do that?

Within the method of

```
-(IBAction)addTap:(id)sender;
```

If not, what type of variable I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
-(IBAction)addTap:(id)sender {
    tapCount++;
}
```

where tapCount would be defined as:

```
int tapCount = 0;
```

The `++` simply adds `1` to the value of `tapCount`.
If you want to add `2` or another number you'd do:

```
tapCount += 2;
```

or if you wanted to reduce the tapCount you'd do:

```
tapCount--;
```

or: `tapCount -= 2;`

Comment: your answer is very detail :D thanks ! i will work my way up hehe

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scope of your variable you just need to increment the `int` variable.

```
int j = 0;
j += 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest would be:

```
-(IBAction)addTap:(UIButton*)sender
{
     sender.tag += 1;
     NSLog(@"count is now: %d",sender.tag);
}
```

which is exploiting the fact that each `UIView` subclass has a property `tag` of type `int` which is often not used.

**warning** sometimes the `tag` property *is* used, see [distinguish the UI buttons on the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372156/distinguish-the-ui-buttons-on-the-iphone/3372217) for an example.

Comment: +1 hehe, how disrespectful - I like this unconventional approach.

Comment: It doesn't follow the MVC approach however, as you are storing data in the view. `tag` should be identifying the UIView only.

Comment: -1 Granted it's funny but this is a dangerous technique and not something to dangle in front of a novice who might not get the joke.

Comment: @mikemike: There are countless ways to solve any problem. This is just one of them, using the least number of lines, but indeed, definitely not the Right Way (TM).

Comment: -1 Same reason as TechZen. I really don't want to see anyone abuse the `tag` property this way.